# Howto build the mysql command string in bash the correct way, preventing " and ' messing up the scenario?

Tags: mysql, string, bash, quotes

I'm trying to use the mysql command line tool from a bash script.

I have two cases that interfere with each other

Case 1: the variable contains **'**

```
rcolumn="Teststring cont'aining a character"
COMMAND="UPDATE "$IMPORT_TABLE" SET colunm='"$rcolumn"' WHERE stepno="$rstepno" ;"
mysql -u "$USER" --password="$PASS" -D "$DATABASE" -e "$COMMAND"
```

now obviously this will mess up the mysql command. The additional **'** character will logically break it.

```
UPDATE table SET colunm='Teststring cont'aining a character' WHERE stepno=1 ;"
```

Case 1 - fixed: to fix above issue I changed the code a little

```
rcolumn="Teststring cont'aining a character"
COMMAND="UPDATE "$IMPORT_TABLE" SET colunm=\""$rcolumn"\" WHERE stepno="$rstepno" ;"
mysql -u "$USER" --password="$PASS" -D "$DATABASE" -e "$COMMAND"
```

now the fixed command will look like below - it will work for this case

```
UPDATE table SET colunm="Teststring cont'aining a character" WHERE stepno=1 ;"
```

However this will introduce case 2: if the variable contains a **"** character

```
rcolumn="Teststring cont"aining a character"
COMMAND="UPDATE "$IMPORT_TABLE" SET colunm=\""$rcolumn"\" WHERE stepno="$rstepno" ;"
mysql -u "$USER" --password="$PASS" -D "$DATABASE" -e "$COMMAND"
```

the above fix logically cannot work in this case.

```
UPDATE table SET colunm="Teststring cont"aining a character" WHERE stepno=1 ;"
```

How can I overcome this issue most effectively?

Comment: also, as some commands may contain both **"** and **'** characters at the same time

Comment: for now I exchanged the actual string ' with **&apos;** to overcome this issue - however that is not  a real solution ;-)

Comment: probably a typo, you are saying `colunm` instead of `column`.

Comment: yes its a typo. sorry

Answer (score 0):

What if you do :

```
rcolumn="Teststring cont'aining a character"
COMMAND="UPDATE "$IMPORT_TABLE" SET colunm="$rcolumn" WHERE stepno="$rstepno" ;"
COMMAND=$"$COMMAND"
mysql -u $"$USER" --password=$"$PASS" -D $"$DATABASE" -e "$COMMAND"
```

source : http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings

Comment: That doesnt seem to work. The string looks like this then:
....SET column=rcolumn ...... instead of the variable content it sets the variable name

Comment: I changed the code if you want to try, sorry if it doesn't work but I can't try this myself ;)